# Spring Data with JPA 2.2 resultStream to Kotlin's Flow

Tags: java, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, kotlin-coroutines

Before JPA 2.2 , if I want to emit `ScrollableResults` to Kotlin's `Flow` , I have to do like this :

```
  override fun findSomeUsers(batch: Int): Flow<User> {
    return flow {
      (em.delegate as Session).sessionFactory.openSession().use { session ->
        val query = session.createQuery("select u from User u where ...")
        query.fetchSize = batch
        query.isReadOnly = true

        query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY).use { results ->
          while (results.next()) {
            val u = results.get(0) as User
            emit(u)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have to downcast `EntityManager` to Hibernate's `Session` .

But since JPA 2.2's `Query` supports `getResultStream` , there should be a cleaner way achieving this :

```
  @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
  override fun findSomeUsers(batchSize: Int): Flow<User> {
    return channelFlow {
      em.createQuery("select u from User u where ...")
        .setHint(HINT_FETCH_SIZE, batchSize) // "org.hibernate.fetchSize"
        .unwrap(javax.persistence.Query::class.java)
        .resultStream
        .asSequence()
        .map { it as User }
        .forEach { u ->
          runBlocking {
            send(u)
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

Well , it works well , but something fishy.

First , why cannot I just code `resultStream.asSequence.map {it as User}.asFlow()` ? (The client side ends as nothing happens)

Second , the `runBlocking` block is ugly. `runBlocking` should only be used in test. But I found no way to circumvent it in the code.

Is there any way to solve it ?

Thirdly , it's not related to the question. It seems Spring-Data-JPA still doesn't support such query method :

```
  @Query("select u from User u where ...") 
  @MaybeSomeQueryHint(batchSize=:batchSize)
  fun findSomeUsers(@Param("name="batchSize") batchSize: Int): Flow<User>
```

It loads all users , then complaining duplicated rows ...

The client(test) side code is as simple as this :

```
  @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
  @Test
  @Transactional
  open fun testUsers() {
    runBlocking {
      userDao.findSomeUsers(100).collectIndexed { index, u: User ->
        logger.info("[{}] {}", index , u)
      }
    }
  }
```

To @Marko , the `Stream` version works well :

```
  override fun findSomeUserStream(batchSize: Int): Stream<User> {
    return em.createQuery("select u from User u where ...")
      .setHint(HINT_FETCH_SIZE, batchSize) // "org.hibernate.fetchSize"
      .unwrap(javax.persistence.Query::class.java)
      .resultStream
      .map { it as User }
  }


  @Transactional // without this annotation , "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed" will be thrown
  @Test
  open fun testUserStream() {
    runBlocking {
      userDao.findSomeUserStream(100).forEach { u ->
        logger.info("{}" , u)
      }
    }
  }


  // it works !!
  @Transactional
  @Test
  open fun testUserStream2() {
    runBlocking {
      userDao.findSomeUserStream(100).asSequence().asFlow().collect { u ->
        logger.info("{}" , u)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of patching up the result of `Stream.toSequence()`, define this conversion of a `Stream` to a `Flow`:

```
fun <T> Stream<T>.asFlow() = flow {
    for (t in iterator()) {
        emit(t)
    }
}
```

If you use it with this code sample:

```
suspend fun main() {
    Stream.of("a", "b")
            .asFlow()
            .collect { println(it) }
}
```

it will print

```
a
b
```

Your function should look like this:

```
override fun findSomeUsers(batchSize: Int): Flow<User> {
    return em.createQuery("select u from User u where ...")
            .setHint(HINT_FETCH_SIZE, batchSize) // "org.hibernate.fetchSize"
            .unwrap(javax.persistence.Query::class.java)
            .resultStream
            .asFlow()
            .map { it as User }
}
```

Comment: Well , the client side code ends as nothing happens , nothing output. (I've added the client side code)

Comment: How did you use it in the server-side code? I added an example. It's not obvious what's the scoping of the JPA session with this approach, but i guess if the session is closed too soon there should be an exception in the consumption code.

Comment: I haven't deploy to server side , I just try the client testing (wrapped with `runBlocking` as shown above) . Your code `resultStream.asFlow().map { it as User}` in fact ends silently as nothing happens (no exceptions too).

Comment: That's no surprise, you get a `Flow` from it. What did you do with the flow you got? If you tried to consume it and still no output, that means the flow was empty, which means the underlying stream was empty. You should first make sure that the code works correctly when using the `resultStream` directly.

Comment: I just print it out , as shown in the `testUsers()` code.

Comment: And you made sure you can print out the data coming from the `resultStream`, without involving the flow? The example in my answer is a proof that `stream.asFlow()` works as expected.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you meant `Stream` . I just modify the code and re-run to test the `resultStream` . It works well ! The client side needs the `@Transactional` annotation , otherwise it throws `Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed` .

Comment: To @MarkoTopolnik , I've appended the `Stream` version . You can check it out.

Comment: Yes, the need for the client-side method to be `@Transactional` is expected, otherwise you are consuming the result set outside of the transaction. You can also try calling `stream.iterator()` to ensure that works as well, and if that works but replacing `stream.forEach` with `flow.collect` doesn't, then I'm out of ideas. It's practically the same code.

Comment: See my updated `testUserStream2()` , it works . It's very interesting... It seems I can only return `Stream` , and in the client side , convert it to `Flow`... (not sure why).

Comment: Why did you use `.asSequence().asFlow()` and not just `.asFlow()`?

Comment: Sure, but did the function `Stream.asFlow()` from this answer work for you? :) If it doesn't work, then there's no point in keeping the answer.

Comment: Thanks , it also works. Thanks for discussion with me.

Comment: OK, great :) So, if you change one thing and one thing only in your working code, and that is to move `.asFlow()` inside `findSomeUsers`, so that the function returns a `Flow` instead of a `Stream`, then it doesn't work? That's really surprising and if so, it may be related to some magic that the annotation processor is doing.

Comment: For anyone who is interested in this question , I've created a Spring-Data-JPA ticket , hoping their `@Query` annotation will be able to return `Flow` . https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1624

Comment: I think maybe because I wrapped another (redundant)  `channelFlow` , that's the reason it completes silently.